# How to stop AJAX function submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on an AJAX function for my site. I'm facing three problems.

1. My page has 2 JavaScript pop-up error message instead of 1 with the same message.
2. Combine the two isset post in the PHP. It doesn't works for me
3. If the `message == success`, how can it submit with the action in the form else it will stay in the same page.

My HTML:

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="contactForm" action="www.alphaexile.com/method?=>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit1"></input>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'success') {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is correct.');
            } else {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is Incorrect.');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</head>
```

My PHP:

```
    <?php

if (!empty($_POST['email'] || ($_POST['email']="Enter Your Email Here")) {
    $status = 'success';
} else {
    $status = 'failed';
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));

?>
```

Comment: check you ajax success functoin, you are resubmitting the form `form.submit()`

Comment: i will fix problem 2

Comment: @andrex , it stills returning even i disable it.

Comment: @Dagon , i've fixed but i need a favor since i'm using onblur function.. in the php i can't put 2 isset post formality like one is empty and another is the onblur.

Comment: I'm not clear with your first question

Comment: @ArunPJohny , For example , i enter an email..
I get a pop up mentioning it's correct then 3-4 second another pop up with the same message appears then only the function takes place.

Comment: I think that is because your submit handler is called multiple times.... add an alert/console logging statement at the beginning of the submit handler to see whether it is called multiple times

Comment: @ArunPJohny, a moment i'll debug it as for number 2 is kinda tricky.

Comment: Hi Jay. We try to discourage the amendment of questions with 'solved' messages, since it is not useful for future readers. Imagine you encounter a Stack Overflow post for the first time, and it says "Question 1, solved, thanks!" and "Question 2, solved thanks!" (etc). It's not very useful. It is much better to allow answers to just stay within answer posts.

Comment: Also, if you feel you have to number sub-questions here, it is sometimes best to ask them one at a time. Remember that questions are meant to be useful for future readers, not just for the original poster.

Comment: @halfer, is it better now ? I mentioned solved so they can review the answers given below.

Comment: No, I've rolled back - it was fine after my edit. Who answered what question is clear below. In general, questions are asked before answers are given, so it can be confusing for new readers who see a question that is written based on answers provided. Again, indicating which question is answered and which is not is a problem with multiple-question posts - another reason why we prefer one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3).

First you need to change the name of the submit button form `submit` to something else then

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var frm = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is correct.');
                frm.submit();
            } else {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is Incorrect.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

For 2) - Not a PHP guy(so I don't know whether you can use $_POST twice, but if you don't want to use it twice). But it looks like the `empty()` call is not properly closed

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
if (empty($email) || $email="Enter Your Email Here") {
    $status = 'failed';
} else {
    $status = 'success';
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to register your execute your ajax code on click of the submit button, then submit the form in the submit action.

```
$('#contactForm [type="submit"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: 'check.php',
    data: {email: email},
    success: function(data){
        if(data.status == 'success') {
            alert('The e-mail address entered is correct.');
            $('#contactForm').submit()
        } else {
            alert('The e-mail address entered is Incorrect.');
        }
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: When i changed it , my ajax suddenly stopped working and it's using my html form action instead.

Comment: I don't see why that would be. Please post your entire code when you changed it and I'll have a look. And you will need to put back the $('form').submit() back in

Answer (score 0):

This should solve all your issue.

You define a global variable, you set it when ajax is finished.   First set it to false, meaning you still need to do some ajax call.  But once the ajax call success you resubmit the form.

This time since you set the checker to true. which means the ajax call is done, it will not perform that call again and instead it will just submit the form.

```
var formSubmit = false;   // define a global variable
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
        if(!formSubmit){
            e.preventDefault();
            var emailParam = $('#email').val();  // change you variable name, it's confusing to read.
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: 'check.php',
                data: {email: emailParam},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.status == 'success') {
                        alert('The e-mail address entered is correct.');.
                         formSubmit = true;  // set the global variable to true.
                         $('#contactForm').trigger('submit')  //resubmit the form
                    } else {
                        alert('The e-mail address entered is Incorrect.');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
           formSubmit = false;
        }
    });
```

For the PHP part you can do it like this

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != 'Enter Your Email Here') {
    $status = 'success';
} else {
    $status = 'failed';
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));
die();
```

Check if `email` parameter is set in `$_POST` and check the value.

Comment: I love you for the PHP part now left number 1 !

Comment: you my javascript code it's should also solve your number 1, 2 and 3.  Just give it a try, there's no harm in trying.

Comment: Erh , no pop up and it didn't read my PHP functions :( .. even right or wrong it still do the html form action.

Comment: Ill update my current one which works with two pop up.

Comment: @JayVicious post the latest one that you said no pop  and it didn't read PHP and differentiate the updates by putting it below so we can see the difference